# Writing regex to capture string with optional lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex which, given these:

```
cache_realm_report__hourly_0.json
filters_0000.json
how_we_feel_emotions.csv
```

returns the respective matches

```
cache_realm_report__hourly
filters
how_we_feel_emotions
```

I have tried a few different patterns but they always fail for one reason or another.

This `^[a-zA-Z_]*(?=\d*\.[csv|json])` almost works except it returns

```
cache_realm_report__hourly_
filters_
how_we_feel_emotions
```

with the last `_` in, which I don't want.

How can I change this to remote the last `_`?

P.S.: I know I could just `replace` afterwards, but I wanted to do everything in regex if possible.

Comment: Replace `[a-zA-Z_]*` with `[a-zA-Z_]*[a-zA-Z]` and add `_*` as the first pattern in the lookahead. You also must use `(?:csv|json)`, not `[csv|json]`. Another approach: `^[a-zA-Z_]*?(?=_?\d*\.(?:csv|json))`

Comment: Alternatively, `[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)*` could give interesting results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z_]*[a-zA-Z](?=_*\d*\.(?:csv|json))
^[a-zA-Z_]*?(?=_*\d*\.(?:csv|json))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ng78Vj/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z_]*` - zero or more ASCII letters or underscores
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `(?=_*\d*\.(?:csv|json))` - immediately on the right, there must be

  - `_*` - zero or more underscores
  - `\d*` - zero or more digits
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?:csv|json)` - `csv` or `json` substring.

The `[a-zA-Z_]*?` part matches zero or more ASCII letters or underscores as few times as possible.